# CompletableFuture uniApply method

Tags: java, java-8, completable-future

I want to know that the using about *uniApply* of Java8 `CompletableFuture` class.

And I fell confused it. For example，the section of the code：

```
private <V> CompletableFuture<V> uniApplyStage(
    Executor e, Function<? super T,? extends V> f) {
    if (f == null) throw new NullPointerException();
    CompletableFuture<V> d =  new CompletableFuture<V>();
    if (e != null || !d.uniApply(this, f, null)) {
        UniApply<T,V> c = new UniApply<T,V>(e, d, this, f);
        push(c);
        c.tryFire(SYNC);
    }
    return d;
}
```

Comment: I also feel confused since I don't find that method in the [docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CompletableFuture.html)

Comment: Its a `private` method belonging to the class `CompletableFuture` which should not ideally be used publically. So what is it and why do you want to seek using this method?

Comment: @nullpointer I think OP is asking what this private method actually does and what it's intended for, etc.

Comment: @FedericoPeraltaSchaffner I agree it seems to be that. But then what in that method implementation is the OP actually looking out an explanation for is unclear to me. (Is it the complete method or a line of code or some argument etc)

Comment: “I fell confused it” is not a question.

Comment: @nullpointer sorry..., I did not explain the qustion clearly. Before I did not understand the using about this method uniApply. And now I think it is used to judge that if the param f  can be executed when uniApply be invoked.

Comment: Thank everyone for replying to me. Next I will reply immediately.